# sequential automatic restart of all datanodes hdfs

Tags: hadoop

I have a Hadoop cluster of over 100 datanodes.It is vanilla Hadoop. There aren't cluster managers like cloudera, ambari, etc.
If I change the configuration hdfs-site.xml for datanodes, I have to restart each datanode.
The cluster is in HA mode and different ETL tasks are constantly do and I have to be careful not to lose data when do restart datanodes
But the situation when each datanode needs to be manually restarted and checked that everything is started is straining.

Do you have any ideas on how to automate this process?
Since the configuration is being rolled out using ansible, I think in this direction.

Comment: I would recommend using Ansible to do a rolling service restart, yes... Is there something wrong you have with that or any error you've ran into before asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Ansible already, it makes sense to use it to restart the datanodes.

If you want to avoid data loss during this, then the best way is to organise the DNs into racks on HDFS, then restart a rack at a time, or if the racks are large, several nodes from the same rack at a time.

If HDFS is configured with multiple racks, it always ensures the data is spread across at least 2 racks.

If you wanted to check if the nodes are back up again, you could poll the NN JMX to check the last contact time for the nodes you just restarted.